# Solving Quadratic Residue Problem

Tags: number-theory

I need to evaluate something like $(\frac{19}{2})$ and $(\frac{-23}{59})$ among several others.

But, I don't quite understand the expectation or the question (what does this notation mean?) Can someone show me how to solve at least one of them? Thank you.

Comment: $\left({-23}{59}\right)$ is a Legendre symbol. It depends on whether or not $-23$ is a square modulo $59$. Since its base is even, I presume $\left(\frac{19}2\right)$ is an Eisenstein symbol. I prefer avoiding these as I can never remember their definition.

Answer (score 1):

Based on your title and your tag, I would surmise that $\left(\frac{a}{p}\right)$ refers here to the [Legendre symbol](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legendre_symbol). It is defined for positive odd primes $p$ and integers $a$ by

$$
\left(\frac{a}{p}\right) =       \begin{cases} 1, & a \textrm{ is a quadratic residue modulo }p \\
0, & p\mid a \\
-1 & a\textrm{ is a quadratic nonresidue modulo }p.
\end{cases}
$$

There are a few properties which would be helpful in computation (in the following, let $a,b\in\Bbb Z$ and let $p > 0$ be an odd prime).

1. If $a\equiv b\pmod{p}$, then
   $$
   \left(\frac{a}{p}\right) = \left(\frac{b}{p}\right).
   $$
2. $$
   \left(\frac{ab}{p}\right) = \left(\frac{a}{p}\right)\left(\frac{b}{p}\right).
   $$
3. [Euler's criterion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%27s_criterion): If $a\not\equiv 0\pmod{p}$, then
   $$
   \left(\frac{a}{p}\right)\equiv a^{\frac{p - 1}{2}}\pmod{p}.
   $$
4. [Quadratic reciprocity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadratic_reciprocity): Let $p$ and $q$ be distinct odd positive primes, and let $q^\ast = (-1)^{\frac{p - 1}{2}}q$. Then
   $$
   \left(\frac{p}{q}\right) = \left(\frac{q^\ast}{p}\right).
   $$
   Moreover,
   \begin{align*}
   \left(\frac{-1}{p}\right) &= (-1)^{\frac{p-1}{2}},\\
   \left(\frac{2}{p}\right) &= (-1)^{\frac{p^2 - 1}{8}}.
   \end{align*}

(Note that $(-1)^{\frac{p-1}{2}}$ depends only on what $p$ is modulo $4$, and $(-1)^{\frac{p^2 - 1}{8}}$ depends only on what $p$ is modulo $8$.)

As an example, let's use the law of quadratic reciprocity to compute $\left(\frac{113}{67}\right)$.
\begin{align*}
\left(\frac{113}{67}\right) &= \left(\frac{46}{67}\right)\\
&= \left(\frac{2}{67}\right)\left(\frac{23}{67}\right)\\
&= (-1)\left(\frac{67^\ast}{23}\right)\\
&= (-1)\left(\frac{-67}{23}\right)\\
&= (-1)\left(\frac{-1}{23}\right)\left(\frac{67}{23}\right)\\
&= (-1)(-1)\left(\frac{67}{23}\right)\\
&= \left(\frac{21}{23}\right)\\
&= \left(\frac{3}{23}\right)\left(\frac{7}{23}\right)\\
&= \left(\frac{23^\ast}{3}\right)\left(\frac{23^\ast}{7}\right)\\
&= \left(\frac{-23}{3}\right)\left(\frac{-23}{7}\right)\\
&= \left(\frac{-1}{3}\right)\left(\frac{23}{3}\right)\left(\frac{-1}{7}\right)\left(\frac{23}{7}\right)\\
&= (-1)\left(\frac{2}{3}\right)(-1)\left(\frac{2}{7}\right)\\
&= (-1)\cdot (-1)\cdot (-1)\cdot 1\\
&= -1.
\end{align*}
This means that $113$ is not a quadratic residue modulo $67$.

As for $\left(\frac{19}{2}\right)$, the Legendre symbol is not defined when the "denominator" is even or composite, but there is the [Kronecker symbol](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kronecker_symbol). It is defined by
$$
\left(\frac{a}{2}\right) =       \begin{cases} 1, & a\equiv\pm1\pmod{8} \\
0, & 2\mid a \\
-1 & a\equiv\pm3\pmod{8}.
\end{cases}
$$
This shares some properties with the Legendre symbol, but one must be a little more careful (check the Wikipedia page for a list of properties).

If for some reason you're using the nonstandard convention where $\left(\frac{19}{2}\right)$ is asking you to determine if $19$ is a square modulo $2$, the answer is easy: any $a\in\Bbb Z$ is a square modulo $2$ ($0^2\equiv 0\pmod{2}$, $1^2\equiv 1\pmod{2}$). Check your book or course notes (or wherever these problems are from) to determine exactly what $\left(\frac{19}{2}\right)$ means.